# How to make MockWebServer work?

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin, mockwebserver

I am developing an app using the MVP architecture. I am trying to test the Interactors of my app using MockWebServer. Well, I have this test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", packageName = "br.com.simplepass.simplepassnew", sdk = intArrayOf(23))
class LoginInteractorImplTest {

    lateinit var mLoginInteractor : LoginInteractor
    lateinit var mServer: MockWebServer


    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        mLoginInteractor = LoginInteractorImpl()
        mServer = MockWebServer()
        mServer.start()
    }

    @Test
    fun loginTest(){
        mServer.url("http://192.168.0.10:8080/login")

        val testSubscriber = TestSubscriber.create<User>()

        mLoginInteractor.login("31991889992", "lala").subscribe(testSubscriber)
        testSubscriber.assertNoErrors()
//        testSubscriber.assertCompleted()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown(){
        mServer.shutdown()
    }
}
```

But, when I uncomment the assertCompleted on the TestSubscriber, I always get assertionError... I know the TestSubscriber works, because I use it in other tests.

Here is my ApiCall:

```
@GET("login")
fun login() : Observable<User>
```

My NetModule:

```
@Module
class NetModule(val mBaseUrl: String) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpCache(application: Application): Cache {
        val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024
        return Cache(application.cacheDir, cacheSize.toLong())

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkhttpClient(cache: Cache) : OkHttpClient {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()

        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        client.addInterceptor(interceptor)
        return client.cache(cache).build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()


          .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }
}
```

And my base URL (There's no backend server... could be anything):

```
<string name="api_base_url">http://192.168.0.12:8080</string>
```

So, What am I missing? This code should be working...

Any help is welcome!

**EDIT:**

So, I changed the code to this:

```
mLoginInteractor = LoginInteractorImpl()
        mServer = MockWebServer()

        mServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBody(Gson().toJson(User(1, "991889992", "Leandro", "123"))))

        mServer.start()

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024

        client.cache(Cache(application.cacheDir, cacheSize.toLong())).build()

        mLoginInteractor.setRetrofit(Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(mServer.url("/"))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
.client(client.cache(Cache(application.cacheDir, cacheSize.toLong())).build())
                .build())
```

And this:

```
val testSubscriber = TestSubscriber.create<User>()

        mLoginInteractor.login("31991889992", "lala").subscribe(testSubscriber)
        testSubscriber.assertNoErrors()
        testSubscriber.assertReceivedOnNext(listOf(User(1, "991889992", "Leandro", "123")))
        testSubscriber.assertCompleted()
```

But I still get this error:

```
Number of items does not match. Provided: 1  Actual: 0.
Provided values: [User(id=1, phoneNumber=991889992, name=Leandro, password=123)]
Actual values: []
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of things going on here.  First, `MockWebServer.url()` resolves the given url against the mock server's base url, it does not set the url.  If you want to set the url, you'll need to pass it to the `start()` method.  Generally, you configure your retrofit to call the server's endpoint --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(server.url("/"))
    // Other builder methods.
    .build();
```

Second, to get responses from the mock web server, you need to enqueue the expected responses as [`MockResponse`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/mockwebserver/src/main/java/okhttp3/mockwebserver/MockResponse.java)s. Otherwise it doesn't know what to send back.  Do something like the following before making your request --

```
server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("Success!"));
```

You'll need to build your response to mirror the expected response.

See the [README](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/mockwebserver/README.md) for some more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer iagreen. I will try this.

Comment: I did exactly like you wrote, but still no luck.